# Why is this copy constructor necessary

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
  private:
    int number;
  public:
    A() {number = 0;}
    A(int nr) {number = nr;}
    //A(const A& rhand) {this->number = rhand.number;}
    int get_number() const {return this->number;}
    A& operator=(const A& rhand) {
      this->number = rhand.number;
      return (*this);
    }
};

class B {
  private:
    vector<A*>* content;
    vector<A*>::iterator currA;
    bool currA_valid;
  public:
    B() {
      content = new vector<A*>;
      currA = content->begin();
      currA_valid = false;
    }
    void push_A(A* nA) {content->push_back(nA); currA_valid = false;}
    void push_A(A nA) {content->push_back(&nA); currA_valid = false;}
    A get_A() {
      if(!currA_valid) {
        currA = content->begin();
        if(!content->empty()) {
          currA_valid = true;
        }
      }
      if(currA == content->end() || this->content->empty()) {
        currA = content->begin();
        return A();
      }
      else {
        A result(**currA);
        ++currA;
        return result;
      }
    }
};

int main()
{
  B container;

  A* a1 = new A(1);
  cout << a1->get_number() << endl;
  A a2(2);
  cout << a2.get_number() << endl;

  container.push_A(a1);
  container.push_A(a2);


  A tmp;
  while((tmp = container.get_A()).get_number() != 0)
    cout << "Inhalt tmp: " << tmp.get_number() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Recently I ran into a problem that I turned into this code snippet.

Essentially class B is a container for objects of class A.

In the actual code A is much larger and the same object of type A may appear several times in the container, so in order to save space, B only stores pointers to A.

The B::push functions feed objects of type A into the container.

They are overloaded for pointers and values of A.

The while-loop at the end of the main-function is what I wanted (kind of like the streaming-operator is used with iostream objects).

An iterator "currA" in B keeps track of which element was last returned by the function call B::get_A(), so successive calls to that function return all the A-objects in B::content until the end is reached. In this case the internal iterator is reset and an object A with an internal invalid-flag (In this case for simplicity A::number is 0) is returned.

The output of this program might look like this:

```
1
2
Inhalt tmp: 1 //content of a1
Inhalt tmp: 4620996 //content of a2
```

The main function instantiates two objects A a1(1) and A* a2(2).

To test A::get_number() both of their internal values displayed. Both work as expected. But after we fed them both into the container and retrieved them from it again only a1 is correctly displayed. The content of a2 shows just some random numbers.

At first I thought, I made a mistake with some of the pointers but it proves that the problem is fixed if one declares and defines the copy-constructor for class A like this:

```
A(const A& rhand) {this->number = rhand.number;}
```

As far as I understood the copy constructor will be implicitly defined by the c++ compiler if none is provided and it is recommended to implement it, when the class has pointers as members to avoid shallow copies. But in this case A only has an int.

I also tried to simplify the code by getting rid of B::get_A() and getting the container content by other means. The problem disappeared even without implementing the default constructor.
So here are my questions:

1.) Isn't the copy constructor the compiler defines similar to the one I provided?
And
2.) What does the copy constructor even have to do with the actual problem? How does implementing the copy constructor solve the problem?

Comment: Use initializing list instead of in-body assigments to initialize class atributtes.

Comment: In the second overload of `push_back` you are storing a pointer to a local copy of the argumment, so after the end of push_back, that pointer is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void push_A(A nA) {content->push_back(&nA); currA_valid = false;}
```

Here, you are taking an `A` object by value. This object is local to the function. When the function returns, the object no longer exists, so your vector is left with an invalid pointer.

Your implementation of the copy constructor had nothing to do with fixing the problem, it was just a coincidence.

Comment: I already noticed that, as you can see in the comments, but this is not an answer to OP's question. Its a comment.

Comment: @Manu343726: It may not be the answer to the OP's question, but it is the solution to his problem.

Comment: No, its not the solution. Its an error relationed with the problem. The problem is not to store a pointer to a copy (Yes, that is an error, but not THE ERROR questioned), is to do a copy without copy constructor. The solution is to suggest OP to study the rule of three.

Comment: @Manu: It's an explanation of what is causing the problem. The OP's question about copy constructors is completely irrelevant to this issue, so I ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If a copy-constructor is not provided, the compiler writes it. But if you define your own assigment operator, or destructor, you should probably define your own implementation of copy-ctor.

In general, if you write a implementation of one of that constructs (Copy-ctor, assigment operator, and/or destructor) you must have to write your own implementation of the others.

This is known as "[The Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)".

Comment: This is wrong. The rule of three exists for *us*, the programmers, to follow. The compiler abides by no such rule. It can and will implement the copy constructor in all cases(regardless of whether an assignment operator or destructor is defined), except where the default implementation would be ill-defined.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, the Rule Of Three is a rule of thumb, not a compiler's rule. But thats not the point. The point is to learn why the code generates an error, and a rule to solve it.

Comment: *"But if you define your own assigment operator, or destructor, the compiler is not allowed to provide a implementation of the copy-constructor."* -- That's the point, and it's wrong.